# tomcat not deploying correctly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

having problem with deploying the application previously worked fine but now tomcat is not able to deploy .It's a maven restful web application using jersey framework .The following error occurs when trying to deploy the application.

```
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.CompositeApplicationEventListener.onEvent(CompositeApplicationEventListener.java:73)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:445)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.resource.listener.ApplicationEventListener$1
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
... 28 more
```

Comment: These error normally will happen if the specified jar is not loaded in the classpath check whether WEB-INF/lib you have that jar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was mvn install was not replacing/refreshing the target folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mvn clean install refresh the project. also check for all the dependencies in pom.xml whether the required dependencies are present or not. That will load all the required classes if previously had not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

After mvn clean install refresh the project. That will load all the required classes if previously had not loaded. also check for all the dependencies in pom.xml whether the required dependencies are present or not.